# Java, вывести числа через пробел

Tags: циклы, java

Пишу на Java. Дано число. Мы не знаем сколько в нем цифр. Нужно по порядку вывести все числа, из которых оно состоит.
Т.е., если num = 1234, выхлоп должен быть таким:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Казалось бы, простейшая задача, но она оказалась для меня непосильной. Вся надежда на вас, уважаемые хешкодовцы :)

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: что-то как то Вы быстро сдались winner

Comment: можно было бы уже и скопировать сюда свои способы решения...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Регулярками

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("");
String[] tokens = p.split(yourString);
```

2) Сабстрингом

```
for (int i = 0; i < yourString.length; i++)
{
     String char = yourString.substring(i, i+1);
}
```

Comment: Если дано именно число, не забыть предобразовать его в строку.

Можно конечно мудохаться с разрядами, целой частью и остатком, но я не вижу смысла.

Comment: @SilverIce: А что, ради прикола можно :) Вы ж не считаете этот вопрос серьёзным, правда?

Comment: @VladD После дня общения с некоторыми клиентами, я готов повериьт, что серьезно может быть задан любой вопрос)

Answer (score 3):

Можно поэлементно выводить:

```
int num = 123;
for (char element : Integer.toString(num).toCharArray()) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Давайте и я напишу извращённый способ.

```
if (num == 0)
{
    System.out.println(0);
}
else
{
    if (num < 0)
    {
        num = -num;
        System.out.println('-');
    }

    const int maxInt10Power = 1_000_000_000;

    bool foundNonZero = false;
    for (int currInt10Power = maxInt10Power; currInt10Power > 0; currInt10Power /= 10)
    {
        int digit = num / currInt10Power;
        if (digit != 0 || foundNonZero)
            System.out.println(digit);
        foundNonZero |= digit != 0;
        num -=  digit * currInt10Power;
    }
}
```

Comment: Тогда уж лучше остатки и стек.

Comment: @avp: Угу, но я хотел за один проход. Не с целью оптимизации, просто попробовать.

Comment: Понятно, только обычно числа маленькие и поэтому способ с остатками будет быстрее.

Просто обычно такие задачки это демонстрация микрооптимизаций (столь "любимых" Вами). Для практики (не обучения) их  ценность близка к нулю.

Comment: @avp: да, так и есть, я ж не в production. В production я бы написал как @Rams666 (за что ему мой +1). Но поскольку верный ответ уже дан, почему бы не поупражняться в извращениях? Сможете продумать более извращённый способ?

Comment: @VladD, все ОК.

Сейчас ничего придумывать не тянет. Влез (из-за одного вопоса тут) в чтение о нейронах.

Comment: @avp: А, видел, не моя тема, хотя конечно надо бы почитать и быть в теме.

Comment: аргумент - несправедливость; я не могу понять почему поставили плюс данному вопросу и тем вытащив его из минуса, учитывая избитость данного вопроса, ленивость квестодателя, особенно учитывая то что сам вопросозадаватель тут до сих пор не объявился. Поэтому я решил поставить минусы всем. Всем спасибо, я кончил.

Comment: @Viacheslav: Не вижу справедливости в выставлении минуса ответу из-за того, что вам не нравится _вопрос_. Я оцениваю ответы обычно по сути самого ответа, и встречал как прекрасные ответы на ужасные вопросы, так и ужасные ответы на прекрасные вопросы (в основном на SO).

Comment: @Viacheslav

К последней фразе.

Рад за вас. Теперь можете помыть руки.

Comment: таки да, теперь я *умываю руки*

Comment: @Viacheslav люто плюсую, о чем вообще спор был тогда в недавнем вопросе о качестве вопросов

Comment: Ой! Детский сад.
Граждане минусователи и рассуждатели о качестве вопросов, вот лично вы - можете "на пальцах" объяснить, как работает и почему именно таков код, предложенный @VladD, в ответе выше?

Comment: @SilverIce ваша шутка про руки очень взрослая.

"На пальцах"? А что в этом коде есть какие-то сложности? Или тех кому не понравился этот ответ, вы считаете тугими на ум?

По поводу почему такой код? Ну видимо посмеяться над автором вопроса, чтобы он не понял (ну или попытался разобраться хотя бы в этом коде, раз не захотел пытаться решить задачу сам, тогда конечно и мотив вроде благородный).

Может вы поясните за что плюс вопросу (раз уж вы назвали нас рассуждающими о качестве вопросов) был поставлен?

Comment: @rasmisha, а что **вопрос** кто-то плюсовал?

IMHO как был 0, так и остался. Совершенно обычный, ничем не примечательный вопрос новичка.

Comment: @avp представьте себе, там был -1 и я поставил -1 (Так что я Вам больше скажу, там 2 плюса, рейтинг кстати об этом тоже намекает 1+20-4)